# holomorphic embeddings of the sphere into the quintic in degree 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, enumerative-geometry

Is there an explicit way of
classifying (with regard to their compatibiliy with $\Omega_+$ or $\Omega_-,$ see below)
the various families of
equivariant holomorphic embeddings from $\mathbb{CP}^1$ to the quintic $Q$, such that $f_*[\mathbb{CP}^1]=2 \in H_2(Q,L;\mathbb{Z})?$

I'd like to know a phenomenology of what one can find, e.g., that only two or three kind of maps would have to be considered, for example the ones giving rise to an open surface, or to an unoriented surface with a crosscap.

Take a *general* quintic $Q$
(for which I don't know a concrete example to write down its equations),
the antiholomorphic involution
$$\sigma: \mathbb{CP}^4 \ni (x_1:x_2:x_3:x_4:x_5) \mapsto (\overline{x}_2:\overline{x}_1:\overline{x}_4:\overline{x}_3:\overline{x}_5),$$
$L$ the fixed locus of $Q$ under $\sigma,$
and $\Omega_\pm: \mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^1 \ (u:v) \mapsto (\overline{v}:\pm\overline{u});$
equivariance means $f\circ\Omega=\sigma\circ f.$

This should be possible in accordance to Clemens conjecture with $d=2,$ which is proved for small $d$ by
[Katz](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=CM_1986__60_2_151_0) (see also [Katz2](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9312009)):
for a *general* quintic, we expect from [Klemm](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0612125) $n^{g=0}_{d=2}=609250;$ it is known that Fermat quintic is not general in the sense of Clemens conjecture, since we have continuous families of maps.

Here $d$ can be thought more or less equivalently either as the homogeneous degree of the map or as the class in $H_2(Q;\mathbb{Z}):$ can this be proved more rigorously, perhaps using the fact that, in the exact sequence
$$ H_2(Q;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z} \to H_2(Q,L;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z} \to H_1(L;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2,$$
the first map is multiplication by 2?

Comment: You have to be careful with the equation of the quintic. The Fermat quintic that you wrote will have more embeddings than a general one.

Comment: A holomorphic map $f$ into ${\mathbb P}_{\mathbb C}^4$ is given by $5$ homogeneous polynomials $p_i$ in $y_0,y_1$ of some degree $d$. I suspect that your  $f_*[S^2]=2\in H_2(Q,L;\mathbb{Z})$ means that $d=2$. The equivariance means that the $p_i$'s have real coefficients. The fact that the map goes to the quintic means that $\sum_ip_i^5=0$. The requirement of $f$ being an embedding means that the matrices $\Big[\frac{d^2p_i}{dy_jdy_k}\Big]_{ij}$ have rank $2$ for $k=0,1$. The moduli space is given by explicit equations in an explicit Zariski open part of ${\mathbb P}_{\mathbb R}^{14}$.

Comment: Well, one should also quotient the above set by the action of $\text{GL}_2{\mathbb R}$ (the real change of variables $y_0,y_1$).

Comment: and also about the quotient; the dimension count should give zero, namely a finite number, as of Clemens conjecture. Can you provide some explicit examples for start, maybe disregarding equivariance for a second? regarding reality, I agree, even if my involution is not exactly complex conjugation

Comment: Your involutions $\Omega_{\pm}$ are complex conjugations on ${\mathbb P}_{\mathbb C}^1$ :all are equivalent modulo the action of holomorphic authomorphisms. (If you would like that your comments reach me, write please @nickname; I do not do so because at this place my comments reach you automatically.)

Comment: The well-known way: take $u^5+1=$ and a point $p:=[p_0,p_1,p_2]$ on the curve $p_0^5+p_1^5+p_2^5=0$. Then $f_p:[y_0,y_1]\mapsto[p_0y_0,p_1y_0,p_2y_0,uy_1,y_1]$ provides a family depending on the parameter $p$ on the quintic curve.

Comment: @LevBorisov do you mean that Fermat quintic is not generic, and thus finiteness as in Clemens conjecture doesn't apply?

Comment: this would fit with @SashaAnan'in example and mine

Comment: @SashaAnan'in could you please provide more details about the condition on the matrix of second derivatives? also, does your dimension count above prove that there will be infinite such curves?

Comment: If you write the map of degree $2$ from ${\mathbb P}_{\mathbb C}^1$ to ${\mathbb P}_{\mathbb C}^n$ in coordinates and require that it is regular at all points, I hope you will get the above matrices. The count should be the same for generic quintic. The point is that, for this particular one, the equations are probably linearly depending. My previous comment is just a shadow of a hint ($d=1$ there) how one can try to find a family when $d=2$.

Comment: 12 edits in two days.